# laravel-admin Image not showing in edit page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I'm working on laravel-admin project. The problem is in edit page image is not showing.
please help me out.
what am I missing here
Thanks in Advance
View Page (Image is displaying)

````
protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new Slider());

        $grid->column('id', __('Id'));
        $grid->column('name', __('Name'));
        //$grid->column('banner', __('Banner'));
         $grid->column('banner', __('Banner'))->display(function ($value) {

            return "<img src='".asset('uploads/' . $value)."' style='max-width:50px;max-height:50px'>";
        });
        $grid->column('created_at', __('Created at'));
        $grid->column('updated_at', __('Updated at'));
        $grid->column('deleted_at', __('Deleted at'));

        return $grid;
    }
    ```
//Details function
  protected function detail($id)
    {
        $show = new Show(Slider::findOrFail($id));

        $show->field('id', __('Id'));
        $show->field('name', __('Name'));
        $show->field('banner', __('Banner'));
        $show->field('created_at', __('Created at'));
        $show->field('updated_at', __('Updated at'));
        $show->field('deleted_at', __('Deleted at'));

        return $show;
    }
     protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new Slider());

        $form->text('name', __('Name'));
      $form->image('banner', __('Banner'))->thumbnail('small', $width = 300, $height = 300);
       return $form;
    }
````

Here is my code image not displaying in edit page
please help me